# Exiting While loop when reaching the end of the string

Tags: python-2.7, list, while-loop

I am currently learning to use ord() and chr() but the having difficulties with the following code.

```
b = '1101'
i = 0
while b != ' ' :
    i = i*2 + ( ord(b[0]) + ord('0') )
    b = b[1:]



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#86>", line 2, in <module>
  i = i*2 + ( ord(b[0]) + ord('0') )
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why does my string go out of range and throw the error instead of exiting the loop as I expect?

Comment: b does not become a space. Where would the space come from? Nice title by the way.

Comment: Your error is based in the while loop and the shrinking string, you might want to take the `chr` and `ord` parts out of the answer and give it a more descriptive title so that future people with the same error can find this answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and a) make the title descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking, so it has some usefulness to future readers here seeing it in a list of search results, and b) be more specific about the problem you're having than *having difficulties*. What **specific difficulties** are you having with the code you posted? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition never becomes true. `' '` doesn't mean Nothing, it means an empty space. Unless your original string contains a space at the end, it will never be true.

It should work if you make it `''` instead of `' '`.

Also, since variables evaluate to `True` when they hold a value and `False` when are reduced to `None` type, you can write the same thing as `while b:` . This will be true as long as `b` holds a value, but as soon as it's empty, it'll stop looping.

Comment: though the more idiomatic way to write that might be `while b:`

Comment: Thanks for confirming that for me I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Yep! All Python objects are "truthy" except empty collections (`[]`, `{}`, `()`, `set()`, etc), `False`, `0`, and the empty string `''` (which I suppose is just an empty collection of characters)